# PHP PDO connection and sql query

Tags: php

I currently have 5 tables in MySQL database. Some of them share foreign keys and are interdependent of each other. I have tested the query in MySQL and it works perfect. When using the query php it is displaying an error with database PDO connection. Also, I am not sure if my PHP will print the results like I am intending. How can I resolve these two issues?

**PHP**

```
<?

try {

    $pdo = new PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT course.id, major.name, course.name, course.code, course.description, course.hours, semester.semester, semester.year
                            FROM course
                            LEFT JOIN major_course_xref ON course.id = major_course_xref.course_id
                            LEFT JOIN major ON major.id = major_course_xref.major_id
                            LEFT JOIN course_semester_xref ON course.id = course_semester_xref.course_id
                            LEFT JOIN semester ON course_semester_xref.semester_id = semester.id");
      $query->execute();

      foreach ($pdo->query($query) as $row) {
        print $row['id'] . "\t";
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['name'] . "\n";
        print $row['code'] . "\n";
        print $row['description'] . "\n";
        print $row['hours'] . "\n";
        print $row['semester'] . "\n";
        print $row['year'] . "\n";
    }

      unset($pdo); 
      unset($query);

?>
```

**Desired Display:**

```
Computer Engeneering
Visual Studio I
CPE1900
Introduction to disciplined, object-oriented programming
4
Fall
2013
```

**Update after Rays answer:** This the error that I get now

```
Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Have you set the database connection variables ($hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `execute()` method returns `FALSE` on error, or `TRUE` if successful. Then you need to fetch the rows one at a time.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

```
if ($query->execute()){

      while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        print $row['id'] . "\t";
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['name'] . "\n";
        print $row['code'] . "\n";
        print $row['description'] . "\n";
        print $row['hours'] . "\n";
        print $row['semester'] . "\n";
        print $row['year'] . "\n";
    }
}
else
    echo 'Could not fetch results.';
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, your dsn connection string indicates mssql and not mysql....

That would cause a connection issue to a mysql database.

Change your connection to this and try again:

```
    $pdo = new PDO ("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbnameU","$username","$pw");
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, it partially fixed the problem now I am running into a different error. Check my posted question for the update.

Answer (score 0):

The PDO prepare method creates a new PDO statement *object*.  Passing $query as a parameter in your example to $pdo->query() will fail because the query method only accepts a string as the parameter.

Both $pdo->query() and $pdo->prepare() return PDOStatement objects, from which you can fetch your results.  The main difference between the two is that query() prepares and executes the statement simultaneously, while prepare() allows you to alter the statement further before execution.  Both use the same methods to fetch results after execution.

Based on your code, I recommend one of the following options:

1) Prepare and execute your statement simultaneously using $pdo->query($sql):

```
$query = $pdo->query($sql);
foreach($query->fetchAll() as $row) {
  //...do something
}
```

2) Prepare and execute your statement separately then return your results:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(); // Note: this returns a boolean, true if successful, false if otherwise.
foreach($query->fetchAll() as $row) {
  //...do something
}
```

Note: for this particular instance, you can ensure the contents of the return type will work with your current code by passing PDO::FETCH_ASSOC as a parameter:

Example:

```
foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
  //..do something
}
```